# How to have Intellij play just the thread I am debugging like eclipse does?

Tags: intellij-idea

In eclipse, if I have 5 threads hit a break point, they all stop (and Intellij does this too).  Then while debugging ONE of those threads, when I hit the play button in intellij it switches out randomly to another thread :(.  In eclipse, if I hit play, it plays JUST that thread until it hits the next breakpoint so I can actually debug ONE of the 5 threads.

Is there a way to do this in intellij?  It makes debugging much much easier to concentrate on that steal thread that is going wrong?  (and then I can also switch between threads as well and hit play on the threads I need to go to the next breakpoint).

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Use the **Thread** breakpoint suspend policy, if you need more details, [read this forum thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206168219-Impossible-to-control-which-thread-is-stepped-in-debugger-Debugger-rapidly-oscillates-between-threads-) and the linked YouTrack tickets.

Comment: none of that worked.  This is NOT a suspend policy issue, but a when I hit 'play button' issue.  It's AFTER.  I guess I will re-ask the question with code.

Comment: @CrazyCoder posted again with more clarity here since that link did NOT work..not sure if that setting is for solving what I am trying to do or not.  new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249855/in-intellij-2020-1-when-i-hit-play-in-debugger-how-to-stop-it-from-switching-t. Perhaps someone might know the answer or just reply it's a bug...not sure right now.